# Faster way to add an `__int128` to an `mpz_class` or `mpz_t` of the GMP library?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, gmp, int128

I want to do this with a [128 bit integer using g++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) and [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)'s `mpz_class` (or `mpz_t`):

```
typedef unsigned __int128 tw_limb_t;

mpz_class a = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
tw_limb_t b = ...;
a += b;
```

I can do the following, but it seems slow to first convert the `__int128` to `mpz_t`:

```
typedef unsigned __int128 tw_limb_t;

inline mpz_class& operator+=(mpz_class &lhs, const tw_limb_t &rhs) {
    if (sizeof(tw_limb_t) != 2 * sizeof(mp_limb_t)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("sizeof(tw_limb_t) is not twice sizeof(mp_limb_t)");
    }

    const int LIMB_BITLEN = sizeof(mp_limb_t) * 8;

    mpz_class rhs_mpz = (mp_limb_t) (rhs >> LIMB_BITLEN);
    rhs_mpz <<= LIMB_BITLEN;
    rhs_mpz += (mp_limb_t) rhs;

    lhs += rhs_mpz;

    return lhs;
}
```

How to get more performance out of this?

Comment: You could manually create a fake mpz_t to avoid the allocation for rhs_mpz, but the code will be likely to break in future GMP updates.

Comment: (See for instance mpz_roinit_n in the doc)

Comment: @MarcGlisse Thanks, that makes it a bit faster on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

This is my current best solution using `mpz_roinit_n` as suggested by Marc Glisse.

```
typedef unsigned __int128 tw_limb_t;

inline mpz_class& operator+=(mpz_class &lhs, const tw_limb_t &rhs) {
    if (sizeof(tw_limb_t) != 2 * sizeof(mp_limb_t)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("sizeof(tw_limb_t) is not twice sizeof(mp_limb_t)");
    }

    mpz_t rhs_mpz;
    mpz_roinit_n(rhs_mpz, reinterpret_cast<const mp_limb_t*>(&rhs), 2);

    mpz_add(lhs.get_mpz_t(), lhs.get_mpz_t(), rhs_mpz);

    return lhs;
}

inline mpz_class operator+(mpz_class lhs, const tw_limb_t &rhs) {
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```